# BeautifulSoup - Modify contents of Tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Given the object `soup` with a value `bs4.BeautifulSoup("<tr><td>Hello!</td><td>World!</td></tr>")`, how do I remove exclamation marks from all `tr` tags?

The closest I have got is:

```
for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    tr.string = tr.decode_contents().replace("!", "")
```

But this results in:

```
<html><body><tr>&lt;td&gt;Hello&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;World&lt;/td&gt;</tr></body></html>
```

Where the angle brackets in `decode_contents()` are encoded when assigned to `tr.string`.

I have also tried `tr.replace_with(str(tr).replace("!", ""))` (using the HTML representation of `Tag` objects) which gives the same result.

Bear in mind this is a simplified example. While I could iterate over the `td` tags instead in this specific example, in reality those tags would also contain HTML structures, presenting the same problem.

Comment: It works perfectly well in my  jupyter notebook. Which IDE are you using? Your first code of tr.string = tr.decode_contents().replace("!", "") works well!

Comment: @JustABeginner I'm using the python REPL in a bash terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You could try iterating through all the string objects that are children of `<tr>`.

```py
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("<table><tr><td>Hello!</td><td>World!</td></tr></table>")

for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    strings = list(tr.strings)
    for s in strings:
        new_str = s.replace("!", "")
        s.replace_with(new_str)
```

One issue is that you can't replace the strings returned by `.strings` without breaking the iterator, which is why I made it a list first. If that's an issue you could iterate in a way that preserves the next element before you replace it, like so:

```py
def iter_strings(elem):
    # iterate strings so that they can be replaced
    iter = elem.strings
    n = next(iter, None)
    while n is not None:
        current = n
        n = next(iter, None)
        yield current

def replace_strings(element, substring, newstring):
    # replace all found `substring`'s with newstring
    for string in iter_strings(element):
        new_str = string.replace(substring, newstring)
        string.replace_with(new_str)

for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    replace_strings(soup, "!", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the following:

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("<tr><td>Hello!</td><td>World!</td></tr>", "html.parser")

for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    replaced_tr = str(tr).replace("!", "")
    modified_tr = bs4.BeautifulSoup(replaced_tr, "html.parser").tr
    tr.replace_with(modified_tr)
```

It seems `replace_with` does not work with strings of HTML, so you should create a `BeautifulSoup` object first and use that as the argument of `replace_with`